# Search all 1st level subfolder names

Tags: c#, subdirectory

I have the following folder structure:

[image]

Each customer folder has project folders under them (which can vary from 1 project folder to 10+ folders). Each project folder is named with a randomly generated 5-digit number and a name.

The goal would be for the user to use a search box and enter either a partial customer name or project ID number (the 5 digit value), and for the app to search and generate a list of folder names that match this information that I can display in a Listbox. My problem though is that there can be dozens of subfolders/files under each project folder with either customer names or the 5-digit ID in their folder name. I don't want the Listbox to display any subfolders deeper then the Project level.

Is there a clean way to search for all folder names that match an input at a parent directory level, and one level down?

Comment: You can probably use [Directory.GetDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Directory_GetDirectories_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_) using the search pattern parameter?

Comment: Get a directory list of parent folder.  Then search through all child folders (for loop) and do not use option to checksubfolders.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suggest *querying* the file system with a help of *Linq*, e.g.

```
  using System.IO;
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  string root = @"C:\MasterFolfer";

  // User Name must contain "user1" substring
  string myUserFilter = "user1";
  // Project Folder must contain "123" substring
  string myProjectFilter = "123";

  var projectFolders = Directory
    .EnumerateDirectories(root)
    .Where(dir => new DirectoryInfo(dir).Name.Contains(myUserFilter))
    .SelectMany(userDir => Directory.EnumerateDirectories(userDir))
    .Select(dir => new DirectoryInfo(dir).Name.Contains(myProjectFilter))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Interesting. I like how simple this is written. I have never used Linq before, so I'll do a bit of research and see if I can make something like this work.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest using `DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories` with the `SearchOption` `Enum` set to 1 but since you only want to look at the first level of subdirectories, this won't do. You could roll your own method like so:

```
public List<string> GetMatchingDirectories(string parentDir, string matchPhrase)
{
        List<string> dirs = new List<string>();
        //get parent directory with parameter of method
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(parentDir);
        //get directories that match in the parent directory
        DirectoryInfo[] directories =
            di.GetDirectories("*" + matchPhrase + "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        //iterate the parent directory matching directories and add to list
        foreach(DirectoryInfo dinfo in directories)
        {
            dirs.Add(dinfo.Name);
            //get the 1st sublevel only of matching directories of current parent dir
            //and add to list
            foreach(DirectoryInfo cinfo in dinfo.GetDirectories("*" + matchPhrase + "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            {
               dirs.Add(cinfo.Name);
            }
        }

        return dirs;
}
```